Type hinting with Python built-in `callable`
In Python 3.10 and later, native type hinting with built-in types became available, along with the | operator to replace typing.Union. I am trying to type hint a callable type without resorting to the typing library.
The following works fine:
def f(a: callable):
    pass

However, when I try to use this with an optional argument, like so:
def f(a: callable | None):
    pass

I get the following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'NoneType'

What is the proper way to hint an optional callable type in this case?

typing.Callable was deprecated in favour of collections.abc.Callable, not callable: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-callables. callable is also not subscriptable, so you can't specify parameter or return types.

The idea of using callable in place of collections.abc.Callable has been proposed at least once, most recently at https://discuss.python.org/t/make-the-built-in-callable-function-perform-double-duty-of-typing-callable-and-iter-for-iterable/59410.
